# Transform a Pandas Series into a Dataframe with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Thank in advance for anyone's help.

I'm trying to transform this Pandas series into a Dataframe with the following logic.

Any time a row from the series starts with "MB" it should create another column in the dataframe, and all the rows below it until the next "MB" should go under that column.

```
MB104
TR15
TR16
SP16
MB301
TR16
SP11
SP16
SP26
SP67
MB302
TR15
MB504
TR15
SP16
SP67
SP109
MB652
SP109
SP110
```

Into this:

```
MB104    MB031    MB302    MB504    MB652
TR15     TR16     TR15     TR15     SP109
TR16     SP11              SP16     SP110
SP16     SP16              SP67
         SP26              SP109
         SP67
```

And this is what I've tried so far

```
mbdf = pd.DataFrame()
assetlist = []
for row in mbs.itertuples():
    left2 = row.data[:2]
    if left2 == 'MB':
        if headername:
            mbdf[headername] = pd.Series(assetlist)
    
    headername = row.data
    assetlist = []
else:
    assetname = row.data
    assetlist.append(assetname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear from your question whether you want them as separate Series or together in the same DataFrame. I assume you want a DataFrame:

```
# Read the data
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
col = None

with open('data.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        if line.startswith('MB'):
            col = line
        else:
            data[col].append(line)
```

If you want a collection of series:

```
series = [pd.Series(value, name=key) for key, value in data.items()]
```

If you want a DataFrame:

```
# Pad every column to the same length
max_len = max(len(v) for v in data.values())

for key, value in data.items():
    value += [None for _ in range(max_len - len(value))]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a example with a list. Every line is explained in code:

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd

# Example data:
example_data = ['MB104','TR15','TR16','SP16','MB301','TR16','SP11','SP16','SP26','SP67','MB302','TR15','MB504','TR15','SP16','SP67','SP109','MB652','SP109','SP110']

# Initialize empty dict of data that will be converted to a dataframe:
final_data = {}

# For every value of the list:
for i in example_data:
    # If start with MB
    if i.startswith('MB'):
        # Save data
        new_mb = i
        continue
    # If MB is in final_data:
    if new_mb in final_data:
        # Append the element (it will be different of MB*)
        final_data[new_mb].append(i)
    # Else: append first element of MB
    else:
        final_data[new_mb] = [i]

# Get the max length of all list values of the dictionary:
max_items = len(final_data.items())

# For every key and list of values:
for key, values in final_data.items():
    # For every value in the list of values:
    for x in values:
        # If length of all list is less than max_items
        if len(values) < max_items:
            # Append empty string:
            values.append("")

# Convert dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(final_data)
```

**Result** (`print(df)`):

```
  MB104 MB301 MB302  MB504  MB652
0  TR15  TR16  TR15   TR15  SP109
1  TR16  SP11         SP16  SP110
2  SP16  SP16         SP67       
3        SP26        SP109       
4        SP67
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mbs` is a `pandas.Series`. You say `series` in you question, but it seems to be a `dataframe` because `series` have no function `.itertuples()`.

```
df = mbs.groupby(mbs.str.startswith('MB').cumsum()).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack(level=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values[1:], columns=df.iloc[0])
print(df)
```

Out:

```
  MB104 MB301 MB302  MB504  MB652
0  TR15  TR16  TR15   TR15  SP109
1  TR16  SP11   NaN   SP16  SP110
2  SP16  SP16   NaN   SP67    NaN
3   NaN  SP26   NaN  SP109    NaN
4   NaN  SP67   NaN    NaN    NaN
```

If you prefer empty strings over `NaN` values (I recommend `NaN` for further analysis)

```
df.fillna('')
```

Out:

```
  MB104 MB301 MB302  MB504  MB652
0  TR15  TR16  TR15   TR15  SP109
1  TR16  SP11         SP16  SP110
2  SP16  SP16         SP67       
3        SP26        SP109       
4        SP67
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'm still amazed at what pandas can do to be honest.!

Comment: @ortunoa If some answer solve your doubt or issue and the answer is helpful, please accept it. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)